# Rails: How to enter value A in Model X only if value A exists in Model Y?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to build a registration module where user can only register if their e-mail is already in an existing database.

Models:

1. User
2. OldUser

The condition on User will be

```
if OldUser.find_by_email(params[:UserName]) exists, allow user registration.
If not, then indicate error message.
```

This is really simple to do in PHP where I can just run a function to execute a mysql query. However, I couldn't figure out how to do it on Rails. It looks like I have to create a custom validator function but seems to be overkilled for a such simple condition.

It should be pretty simple to do. What have I missed?

Any pointer?

Edit 1:

This solution by dku.rajkumar works with a slight modification:

```
validate :check_email_existence
    def check_email_existence
      errors.add(:base, "Your email does not exist in our database") if OldUser.find_by_email(self.UserName).nil?
    end
```

For cases like this, is it better to do validation in the model or at the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it as

```
if OldUser.find_by_email(params[:UserName])
   User.create(params) // something like this i guess
else
   flash[:error] = "Your email id does not exist in our database."
   redirect_to appropriate_url
end
```

**UPDATE:** validation in model, so the validation will be done while calling `User.create`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :check_mail_id_presence

// other code
// other code

  private

  def check_mail_id_presence
     errors.add("Your email id does not exist in our database.") if OldUser.find_by_email(self.UserName).nil?
  end

end
```

Comment: Thanks. This will live in the controller then? Am I able to call on any Model in a controller? I have one User controller and two models.

Comment: Thanks for the answer dku.rajkumar. I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend starting with [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise).

See https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

Even if you have unusual needs like these, you can normally adapt it. Once you get to know it, it's extremely powerful, solid and debugged, and you can do all sorts of things with it.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. I think I will look at Devise a bit later because this is my first Rails application, and it is already too much to be swallowed.

Answer (score 0):

Bellow is just an initial implementation .../app/controller/UsersController for User registration related actions.

```
 def new
  @user = User.new
 end
 def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])
  @old_user = User.find_by_email(user.email)
  if @old_user 
     if @user.save
      # Handle successful save
     else
     render 'new' # and render some error message telling why registration was not succeed 
     end
  else
   # render some page with some sort of error message of 'new' new users
  end
 end
```

**Update:**
Check out the following resources for more info:

- [Ruby on Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/)
- [Rails: User/Password Authentication from Scratch, Part I/II](http://rubysource.com/rails-userpassword-authentication-from-scratch-part-i/)

Comment: You very welcome John. Once u've solved the problem u run into don't forget to up-vote and accept the an answer.

Comment: I'm trying your solution now. Is it better to put this type of validation in Model or controller? I know that people always say "fat model" but does it apply for this case?

Comment: You can  define can_register?  method in the model just to maintain consistent level of abstraction.  You still need to invoke can_register? from the create action in the controll.